# If there was a way to back out implied volatility (IV) from a stock, would it be the same as the IV backed out from an option on that same stock?

Tags: options, equities, implied-volatility, risk

I know that it is not possible to back out an IV for a stock, because the concept of IV is based on a model with underlying assumptions applied to pricing an option.

I was thinking of why IV is forward looking, and I realised that it was because the price of the option reflects all the current available information that investors had at that moment and also their expectations of where the asset price was going. Therefore, the IV backed out would be an expectation of future risk.

Therefore, by this logic, shouldn't a stock price reflect all the current available information that investors had at that moment and also their expectations of where the asset price was going? And if an IV could be backed out, shouldn't it reflect its future expected risk?

Comment: Under the assumption that $dS_t = rS_tdt + \sigma S_tdW_t$, sure. But in reality, we know $r$ and $\sigma$ aren't constant. Close to expiration ATM IV is a good indicator of $\sigma$ at $t_0$, but IV > realised vol most of the time, except during black swan events. Options are used to model vol because options are really only dependent on vol. But on the other hand, it's reasonable to assume $S_t$ relies on many more parameters, i.e. SLV/SV models. This is why many sophisticated traders do not trade direction, because it's a lot harder to model the dynamics of the stock, compared to vol

Comment: But you can use IV from options to model $S_t$, you just need more factors to consider the "true" dynamics of $S_t$

Comment: @THAT'SMYQUANTMYQUANTITATIV, thank you for the reply! It certainly gave me some ideas.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58507

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, IV is indeed possible, at least in theory, to back out of stock prices. This lies, I would say, in the core of the so called structural bond models, which, as far as I know, started out with [Robert C. Merton's work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merton_model). It is much the same logic for options:

Option price = f1(IV, strike, maturity, Stock Price)

as it is for stocks:

Stock price = f2(IV, default boundary = g1(default costs, total firm debt,...), maturity, firm value = g2(Bond price, Stock Price))

The fact that IV is a parameter in both the Stock-to-option-price relation and in the Bond-to-stock-price relation shows up in [the positive correlation between corporate bond spread indices and IV-measures such as the VIX](https://www.pennmutualam.com/market-insights-news/blogs/chart-of-the-week/2018-05-10-u-s-high-yield-credit-spreads-vs-sp-500-vix).

However, in practice the approach is complicated by equity and debt values constantly changing with dividends, stock-buybacks, possible equity-issuance, new funding and redemptions. Assymetric information between stakeholders with equity being usually more informed and hard-to-predict default costs makes the whole firm capital structure quite a game to play.

Nevertheless, there are simplifications that lead to closed-form solutions such as the Leland 1994 model.

Comment: Thank you Mats for the reply, is there a particular paper you are referencing by Merton? Or is it the famous 1976 paper? Lastly, is there a particular closed form solution to the stock price (that you specified above) similar to the Black-Scholes closed-form solution to European options?

Comment: Merton, Robert C. (1974). "On the Pricing of Corporate Debt: The Risk Structure of Interest Rates" see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merton_model

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the more recent [_Capital Structure Arbitrage under a Risk-Neutral Calibration_ by Peter J. Zeitsch, 2017](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/10/1/3/pdf) and the literature review in it.